# htaccess permanent redirect and remove string from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How can I go about getting visitors who enter the site via a mobile url get redirected to the non mobile url on this example;

> user visits http://website.com/**mobile/**the-page.html 
>   redirect them to http://website.com/the-page.html

Doing a google search, I was able to come up with the follow htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?mobile/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

though it correctly redirects to the right page, it uses the filename of the dynamic page to do so, example:

> http://website.com/index.php?id=the-page

how can I get it to just take out mobile/ from the url?

Answer (score 1):

okay, slow moment... I needed to deleted the original rewrite rules for the mobile site.

after that, it was simple as adding

```
RewriteRule ^mobile/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to htaccess.